# Making word like in Image in Horizontal and Vertically from Gridview

Tags: java, android, gridview

My problem is i want to concatenate the word and read it horzontely and vertically from  cell position of the grid view. I have gridview position and the word that I place on the gridview here is the image and code .
[image]

```
private  HashMap<String,String> result = new HashMap<String, String>();

 String postionOfCell = GridViewPosition;

 String alphabetName = imageView.getTag().toString();

   m.put(postionOfCell, name);
```

I put the name and position this way.!

[Make Name BAC ,BA , AA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OFMvP.png)

Comment: Also Face this problem if you find then please help me ...